# Get package calling to ContentProvider before API 19

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, pid, uid

My goal is to get the name of package calling to I've tried to leveraget calling PID and UID, but I've yet to find the way that doesn't include parsing terminal response for active processes. There is a method in PackageManager to get package name for UID, but it returns multiple package names. So, is there a way?

Comment: Have you tried saving App's context and getting the package name from it?

Comment: Has anyone figured this out?